# insert node in neo4j is very slow

Tags: .net, performance, insert, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to insert a single node in my graph without any relationships and it takes 1/10 sec, so when I need to insert 10 nodes that should take 1 sec which is a lot comparing with some results I found in my google search for some people who claim to insert 30k nodes in 1 sec. 

 
I use the neo4jclient with cypher queries to do that :

```
            gclient.Cypher
   .Create("(p:Post {newPost})")
   .WithParams((new
   {
       newPost = post
   }))
   .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Is there something I miss ? thanks in advance

**Edit :** I'm using neo4jclient with .net .

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're using a REST API client, i.e. connecting to a web endpoint.  That involves of course going through multiple protocol layers (JSON, HTTP, etc), and tends to be slower.

People who are doing 30k nodes in 1 second aren't going through the REST API, they may be using [batch insertion](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/batchinsert.html), the [import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html), or possibly [LOAD CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html).

Comment: please note that it depends of the performance of the api client too (e.g. instantiation etc..), 100ms for 1 node is really slow, I can run 1200 cypher statements in around 180ms via the rest api.

Comment: @Christophe Willemsen , can I make a contact with you via email? I have a lot of questions about this,, but if you can't :) ,, I can ask here : how you can achieve such a result ? thanks in advance.

Comment: the answer is easy, small statements in one transaction and commit(); unfortunately for .net I'll not be able to help that much

Comment: what do you mean by small statements in one transaction and commit() ? can you give an example ? thank you

Comment: I think what Christophe was saying is that, when writing to the graph, you have to take into account many different things. There's the overhead/inefficiency of REST, there's the drivers, but there's also the overhead of ACID transactions. In many cases, you will need/want to tweak the size of the transactions that you are doing. if begin/commit every single write atomically, there's going to be a big overhead. If you batch several statements together in 1 transaction, the overhead per write will be smaller. That's what "small statements in one transaction" means, I believe.

Comment: Generally I think everyone here has it right - the only problem you have is that `neo4jclient` doesn't handle transactions at the moment. If you're looking to get that speed and it's just a one-off type thing (initialising for example) - I would look at the import tool or load csv as @FrobberOfBits said.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check your indexes and constraints. Unique constraints can slow down inserts and updates dramatically.